# Symfony Native Query

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine, twig, dql

I work on a project under symfony, when I want to calculate the average product by month and year (date) and as doctrine doesn't include the Month or YEAR functions I used native sql but it didn't show the results, it return empty array.

If someone can help me,Thank you.

Repository:`

```
public function MonthEfficience()
{
 $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());

$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('GP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Efficience', 'e');

$rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('GP\PlatformBundle\Entity\collectif', 'c', 'e', 'collectif', array('id' => 'collectif_id'));

$sql = 'SELECT (AVG(e.produit_real/e.produit_plan)*100) as moyenne, 
 MONTH(e.date) as mois, YEAR(e.date) as annee FROM efficience e, collectif c 
where e.collectif_id=c.id group by mois, annee';

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

$resultats = $query->getResult(); 

return $resultats; 

}
```

Controller:

```
public function effmonthAction()
{

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()

->getRepository('GPPlatformBundle:Efficience');

$efficiences = $em->MonthEfficience();   

return $this->render('GPPlatformBundle:App:effmonth.html.twig', 

array('efficiences'=>$efficiences));

}
```

Twig :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Annee</th>
                        <th>Mois</th>
                        <th>Moyenne</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for efficiences in efficiences %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ efficiences.produitplan }}</td>
                            <td>{{ efficiences.produitreal }}</td>
                            <td>{{ efficiences.produitplan }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Resultats:
  empty array

Comment: It is actually pretty easy to add Month/Year functions: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions